# Foreach loop doesn't echo anything

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

i'm working on my project.
I have table with racers (ID, name, surname etc.) and I stored it in an array.
Then i used foreach loop to echo this data, but nothing show up.
This is my code:

```
$zavodnici_array = array();
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
$zavodnici_array[] = $row;
}  
foreach($zavodnici_array as $key) {
  echo $zavodnici_array[$key][id] ."<br>";
  echo $zavodnici_array[$key][jmeno] ."<br>";
  echo $zavodnici_array[$key][prijmeni] ."<br>";
}
```

Can anybody help me? :)

Comment: Try `echo $key['id'] ."<br>";`

Answer (score 2):

THere are a few things wrong with your example.

when using `foreach as $key` key is the value of each item in the array not the key

ass uming your `mysql` query fetched results

```
foreach($zavodnici_array as $key => $value) {
  echo $zavodnici_array[$key]['id'] ."<br>";
  echo $zavodnici_array[$key]['jmeno'] ."<br>";
  echo $zavodnici_array[$key]['prijmeni'] ."<br>";
}
```

or

```
foreach($zavodnici_array as $value) {
      echo $value['id'] ."<br>";
      echo $value['jmeno'] ."<br>";
      echo $value['prijmeni'] ."<br>";
    }
```

keys in php are strings or integers `$value[id]` is not valid.  I assumed you were trying to type the index `id`

Comment: Ohh, yes. Really thanks :) Now I understand how foreach works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining your own values for the array you must use this:

foreach ($array as $key => $value)